# Tag removed twice though it seems to be in the right place

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, specific-question

I'm a bit embarrassed, about edit activity on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035897/chess-playing-algorithm-which-plays-with-itself). Since I don't want to run into an "edit war", I prefer to ask here.

Granted, the question is not asked well, and the OP does not show much work. Nevertheless, he is explicitly asking for a Lisp or Prolog implementation, hence, it seems obvious to me that it can be tagged with [lisp](/questions/tagged/lisp) and [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog). However, [lisp](/questions/tagged/lisp) was removed twice by the same editor, without comment. What's the problem?

Comment: You can ask the reason to the editor with [`@Reply`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: I don't know this feature. Where can I @Reply ? (it's merely out of curiosity for the next time I encounter this problem, since this question has been closed anyway)

Comment: If you use `@username` in comments the user will get notification in his inbox. So he may reply you with reason. You can also reply to the editor. (e.g. use `@Rainer` in this case.)

Comment: Meh, the tags are irrelevant. Stack Overflow is not a site for code requests.

Comment: @hims056, ok, I really didn't know it notifies the user! Thank you.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, yes, the question is bad, but this has nothing to do with tags.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, questions should only contain 2 language tags if the question specifically requires knowledge about **both** to be answered (not either).

A question that does not fall into the above category most likely isn't an appropriate question for StackOverflow, as it would, from my experience, likely be asking for code without `"demonstrat(ing) a minimal understanding of the problem being solved"` (which happens to be the close reason for the question in question). If this is the case, both tags may actually be appropriate in theory but, since the question isn't, the tags aren't particularly significant - both, either, neither - as long as the question gets closed, it doesn't really matter.

Or it shouldn't have both language tags, and the one should simply be removed to make it appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: I understand the question has nothing to do here, it was just about removing a possibly useful tag. But I do agree, as long as the question is closed, it doesn't matter. I was just quibbling, actually. Thanks for your answer :-)